# .Net Parallel, Task APIs Vs regular Threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing

As I understand Parallel API use the Thread pool internally and they queue up the items for parallel processing, however, when I checked up the execution of one such parallel loop using SOS debugger, then my understanding is that if I have 10 tasks lined up then all of them might not go in parallel and CLR would decide how many threads to dispatch for the given tasks to be executed, so it may be 4 or 5 or 6 (varied number in each execution)

However in case my total task number if not very high like 10 and I want all of them to go in parallel, since all of them are long running, then it is preferable to have them on Traditional threads, which will ensure 1 thread per task and they all go in parallel
In case the number of tasks are good number like 100, then usage of Parallel or Threadpool is a practical solution, as we do not want to invoke 100 individual threads per process

Please share your view, I understand the benefit of Parallel API making complete Parallel programming very easy to implement, but here my aim is different

Comment: Just use the TPL. This is quite an open subjective question, you don't clearly specify what your aim is and make some disconnected assumptions in the question. "Regular Threads" aren't magic, they will still be constrianed be the physical hardware and operating system.

Comment: @Jodrell: Threads use pre-emptive time-slicing, allowing any number to run in parallel (with increasing overheads). Without the `LongRunning` option, TPL would be inappropriate for scenarios requiring many tasks to be active simultaneously (even if only virtually so).

Comment: @Douglas, it depends on what the OP means by long running. Either way, it makes sense you to use TPL. If the work is "Long Running" then your answer, which I already upvoted, applies nicely. If I create 1000 "Regular Threads" they will perform as equally badly as 1000 `LongRunning` TPL `Tasks`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, the .NET thread pool initializes a number of worker threads that corresponds to the number of logical cores on your machine. It subsequently employs a hill-climbing heuristic that adjusts this number based on the current task workload, firing up new worker threads when a task takes too long to complete.

You are correct in wishing for your long-running tasks to be executed simultaneously through thread oversubscription (i.e. running multiple threads per logical core). In fact, the Task Parallel Library infrastructure (TPL) provides specifically for this scenario through the [`LongRunning`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions.aspx) option, which (under the current implementation) spawns a new dedicated thread for each task marked thusly.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(myLongRunningAction, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```